# Minimum requirements of Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10, system-requirements

Does anyone know what are the minimum requirements to install Ubuntu 20.10?

Comment: If your hardware doesn't meet the recommended minimums, lighter *flavors* are an option (I test using hardware that has a c2d cpu & 2GB only of ram), however it'll still depend how you use the box, what software you want/need to use, whether or not they'll help. Smaller disks sizes also work, however it'll depend on what software you'll install, if you plan on *release-upgrading* in place, or clean-install to upgrade the amount of disk space needed (25GB allows for *release-upgrade* instead of *nuke & install* bloggers often prefer.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended minimum requirements are outlined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for the Desktop version and [here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation) for the Server version.

Minimum recommended requirements for desktop version:

- 2 GHz dual core processor
- 4 GiB RAM (system memory)
- 25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

Minimum recommended requirements for server version:

- 1 GHz processor
- 1 GiB RAM (system memory)
- 2.5 GB of hard-drive space

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Ubuntu Desktop Edition

```
2 GHz dual core processor
4 GiB RAM (system memory)
25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful
```

And graphic recommendations

```
4096 MiB RAM (system memory) for physical installs.
2048 MiB RAM (system memory) for virtualised installs.
3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB
```