# Can I run Ubuntu 20.10 smoothly on Intel Pentium G3220?

Tags: intel, cpu, 20.10

I use a desktop with a 4GB Ram and Intel Pentium Gold Processor. Can I run Ubuntu 20.10 smoothly on the desktop?

Comment: Question is already asked and answered. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302021/minimum-requirements-of-ubuntu-20-10#:~:text=2%20GHz%20dual%20core%20processor,capable%20of%201024x768%20screen%20resolution

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can**. 
Here are the installation/system requirements for Ubuntu 20.04 -

- 2 GHz dual-core processor
- 4 GiB RAM (system memory)
- 25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card, or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

Comment: How do you know what he says is "smoothly" is the same as what you call "smoothly"? :)

Comment: @Rinzwind Sometimes all you need is a leap of faith :)